# By using Express-fileupload library ,Upload image to AWS S3 bucket

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

any one please help me, by using express-fileupload library, I want to upload my file and image to AWS S3 bucket using restful API.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you found the answer.
In case you haven't found the answer, here is what I just found out

```js
const uploadSingleImage = async (file, s3, fileName) => {
  const bucketName = process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME;
  if (!file.mimetype.startsWith('image')) {
    return { status: false, message: 'File uploaded is not an image' };
  }
  const params = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: fileName,
    Body: file.data,
    ACL: 'public-read',
    ContentType: file.mimetype,
  };

  return s3.upload(params).promise();
};
```

```
s3.upload(params).promise()
```

will return an object which contains the Location of the file you uploaded, in fact you could generate it yourself but that would not cover in case any error occur so I think what I posted here is a better solution.